# How to use liquid template in jsp?

Tags: node.js, jsp, liquid, shopify-template

I have a liquid based template that I need to parse. I am working on spring framework that returns JSP as view(template here) for some specific endpoint.
I saw [liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid) documentation for installing it on rails based app, also came across [link](https://github.com/docs/liquid) that enables to use liquid with Nodejs based app.

I have liquid template returned by an api and some other api that returns data to be filled in template, I wanted to know is there any way I can configure liquid for JSP such that the JSP returns the parsed liquid template as view?

Answer (score 1):

I found out bundled js: https://liquidjs.com/tutorials/setup.html#LiquidJS-in-Browsers support that can be configured to work with liquid template in JSP or anywhere.

Usage:

```
<script type="text/template">
<h3>{{ name | capitalize | prepend: "Welcome to "}}</h3>
</script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

js:

```
const template = document.querySelector('[type="text/template"]')
const result = document.querySelector('#result')
const engine = new liquidjs.Liquid()

engine
    .parseAndRender(template.innerHTML, {name: 'liquid'})
    .then(html => result.innerHTML = html)
```

Here is the demo for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/pd4jhzLs/1/